# How to properly and for once reinstall PHP/Apache

Tags: macos, homebrew, apache, php

So I'm struggeling with this since a long time and I'd like to find a proper solution.

I have php5.4.. install and I want to upgrade to Php 7.

No matter how hard I'm trying to do it I can't seems to touch my goal.
I tried to remove php54 and other with homebrew, to remove it manually by command line, to overwrite it with new version nothing work. What ever Im doing when I type `php -v` I always end up with php5.4 :

```
Marjorie:~ Mawel$ php -v
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Sep  6 2015 20:56:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

So I'm asking my self have I messed up with my php/apache conf ? Shall I try a clean-install of my system and would it be efficient ? I don't know ! I'm kinda lost and really need some help even for comprehension (is there a reason I can't get rid of old php version ?)

Anything would be helpful

### Edit

So here is more information for answering the questions :

Output of `brew tap`

```
Marjorie:~ Mawel$ brew tap
homebrew/dupes
homebrew/php
homebrew/versions
```

As of what I've tried with home brew : 
So here is step by step the idea :

```
brew remove php54
brew install php70
brew link php70
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.4
```

Lets add this information :

```
Marjorie:~ Mawel$ sudo find ~/ -iname "php"
/Users/Mawel//Code/agencedevoyage/sos-partenaire/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/tests/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Code/agencedevoyage/sos-partenaire/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Code/agencedevoyage/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/tests/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Code/agencedevoyage/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Code/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Code/Site Perso/dev/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/tests/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Code/Site Perso/dev/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Documents/Cours/BTS SIO/Developpement/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Documents/Cours/BTS SIO/Developpement/web/php
/Users/Mawel//Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Cache/PHP
/Users/Mawel//Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/static/components/codemirror/mode/php
```

And finally, my bash profile :

```
Marjorie:~ Mawel$ vi ~/.bash_profile

alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Calm down mate :) First of all tell us what brew commands have you tried and `brew list` which php version gives you

Comment: Also, what's the output for `brew tap`?

Comment: @Alessiox Edited my post

Comment: Since you're working with homebrew, first of all I'd suggest to `brew update` and `brew cleanup` to remove older formula versions and leftovers/cache. Then in your `PATH` try putting `usr/local/bin` (where brew links stuff) before `usr/bin` (the apple standard)

Comment: if you type `which pip` I reckon the Terminal will print `/usr/bin/php`, which is the Mac OS X standard (pre-installed) PHP release

Comment: `Marjorie:~ Mawel$ which pip`
`/Users/Mawel/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pip`

And did everything else but no amelioration

Comment: dude I'm so sorry. Not `which pip` but `which php`. I got confused, Canopy is indeed python-related and so is `pip`

Comment: Haha indeed I was asking my self too :) So here you got it : `Marjorie:~ Mawel$ which php`
`/usr/bin/php`

Comment: As you can see the default `php` is not the homebrew `php` but the standard Mac OS X. Mac OS X as you might know, scans the `PATH` from top to bottom when looking for executables and binaries, so the `usr/local/bin` path (which is the homebrew path) should be at the top of the `PATH` (or, at least, before `usr/bin`. Try changing the `bash_profile` including the brew path at the top of the `PATH`, then restart and try again with `which pip` or `pip -v` and see if something changes.

Comment: Your `PATH` definition is split in several lines, to make sure that the changes are ok, type in Terminal `echo $PATH`. This command will show the entire `PATH`, so you can easily check if `usr/local/bin` comes before `usr/bin`

Comment: Well I've did it and restarted Apache I restart the whole computeur in a sec

Comment: Great It works !! So it was all about `PATH`  Post answer below and I accept it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `brew` commands look ok. You have all the taps you need.
First of all since you're working with homebrew, I'd suggest the following two commands (let's start clean):

```
brew update && brew cleanup
```

So we're sure that we're using the latest homebrew release and we cleanup all old formulas and leftovers.

From your `PATH` it looks like `usr/bin` (which is the standard Mac OS X path for binaries and executables) comes before `usr/local/bin` (the path in which homebrew links the Cellar).
As you might know, Mac OS X when looking for binaries/executables scans the `PATH` from top to bottom so if both `usr/bin` and `usr/local/bin` have the `php` executables, since `usr/bin` comes first in `PATH`, then Mac OS X will use the `php` version in such folder, ignoring the version in `usr/local/bin` (which, as instead, is our target).

To make sure regarding which version Mac OS X is using, type in the Terminal

```
which php
```

and if the output is `usr/bin`, then Mac OS X is using its own version.

The core indeed now is to change the `PATH` order in `bash_profile`, and make sure that `usr/local/bin` comes before `usr/bin` (it is clear now that we're forcing Mac OS X to use the homebrew version).

Once the changes have been done, restart your Mac and type in the Terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

This will display the entire `PATH` list so you can make sure everything's in the right order.
Now, finally, you can check using either

```
which php
```

or

```
php -v
```

which is the running version.